# How to verify if a form is valid in Django CBV post method?

Tags: django, validation, django-forms, django-views, django-class-based-views

I have a customized sign-up form that looks like this:

```
class AdminSignupForm(UserCreationForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(AdminSignupForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # remove username from the form (we will autogenerate a random one)
        self.fields.pop('username')

    class Meta:
        # Set this form to use the User model.
        model = User

        # Constrain the UserForm to just these fields.
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'title', 'email')

    def save(self, commit=True):
        random = ''.join([choice(letters) for i in xrange(30)])
        self.instance.username = random
        return super(AdminSignupForm, self).save()
```

The view for the form is:

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    super(AdminSignupView, self).post(request, *args, **kwargs)
    # ... do some things based on the form fields (i.e create object instances, etc.)

    return reverse("home")
```

What I want to do is to verify the form and return the right HttpResponse if it's not valid. The thing is that I need to call super() before I do some actions as the parent class post() created a User for me. I thought doing something like getting the return value from the post super() and checking it to see if the form isn't valid -I saw in the django source code that it returns a render_to_response, but it looks very ugly to search for errors there. I'm sure that there is a better solution just can't get my head around it...

Answer (score 4):

Have you considered using a FormView?

```
from myapp.forms import AdminSignupForm
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.views.generic.edit import FormView

class SignUpView(FormView):
    template_name = 'path/to/signup-template.html'
    form_class = AdminSignupForm
    success_url = reverse("home")

    def form_valid(self, form):
        # This method is called when valid form data has been POSTed.
        # It should return an HttpResponse.
        return super(SignUpView, self).form_valid(form)

    def form_invalid(self, form):
        # This method is called when invalid form data has been POSTed.
        return super(SignUpView, self).form_invalid(form)
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormView